# Most efficient way to load classes in PHP

Tags: php, object, loading, require

I'm a c# developer, so I'm used to simply compiling a library and including it within a project for use. I haven't really figured out the best way to load different objects within a PHP application. I don't want to keep using require. What is a good approach to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.x, you probably want [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: Zend autoloader http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html is good example for loading classes automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to keep using `require`.  You can `require_once()` which will only parse the file if it has not already been loaded.

Also in PHP, since the includes happen at runtime you are free to `require_once()` in the middle of a conditional if it is appropriate.

```
// Only load Class.php if we really need it.
if ($somecondition) {
  // we'll be needing Class.php
  require_once("Class.php");
  $c = new Class();
}
else // we absolutely won't need Class.php
```

Answer (score 1):

I was C# developer in the past and I can tell you that you need to think bit different if you want to write PHP sites. You need to keep in mind that every unnecessary include will increase extra expenses of resources, and your script will work slower. So think twice before add unnecessary includes.

Back to your question you can use [include](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [autoload](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php) or even [phar](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php). Probably PHAR is more close to C# libraries, you can include one PHAR libraries with a number of classes.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your config file( or any file included in all pages )

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once "Classes" . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

Put every class in seperate file with its name.
replace "`Classes`" with your `classes folder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload classes. See:

- https://www.php.net/autoload

From that page:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Note that you can use `spl_autoload_register()` if you don't want to use the single magic `__autoload` function.

Comment: What if my objects reside inside different folders? Would this fail? Or is there a good way to handle those cases?

Comment: You have to keep track on it. PHP will not do it for you.

Comment: @Dietpixel, you have to come up with some solution. Often, you can just do something as simple as class `Foo_Bar` resides at `Foo/Bar.php`; that is, always put the class in a location that can be determined by its name. If you don't do that, you'll need to use some other method to map a class name to a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

The [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Autoloader, as others mentioned.

If you want to go step further... look at the way how [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/autoloading) (for example) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question is the first Stack Overflow result from searching "php how to load classes" and other answers which provide examples for autoloading suggest the use of `__autoload()`. **Please note that use of `__autoload()` is [deprecated as of PHP 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) and its use is discouraged**. Using [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is [suggested instead](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

The example snippet below is from the documentation page:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    include 'classes/' . $class_name . '.php';

});
```